# Loading json file gives code 404.3

Tags: json, model-view-controller, datatables, http-status-code-404

I have DataTables translations stored in .json file. In debug mode I get code 404.3.

I have read many articles about this problem but I can't find anything helpful.
I've added the section below to config file but this did not help.

This MIME type is also configured in my IIS.

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to simply rename the file to `.txt`, it should work just fine.

Comment: It works, but must be a reason of problem with .json file.